# svg - <tspan> inside <text> is not visible in FF and Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, safari, tspan

I am trying to figure out why text inside `<tspan>` are not visible in FF (v31) and Safari (in Chrome it works). Code which generates texts:

```
var year_elements_text = document.createElementNS(NS, "text");
year_elements_text.setAttribute('x', String((i * year_all_elements_width) + rect_width + (line_width / 2)) + "px");
year_elements_text.setAttribute('y', String(text_starting_point) + 'px');
year_elements_text.setAttribute('style', 'text-anchor: middle');

year_elements_text.innerHTML = '<tspan>' + String(starting_year + i) + '</tspan>';

g_tl.appendChild(year_elements_text);
```

Full code is [here (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/picode/L01xh1rr/).

Without `<tspan>` in works in Chrome and FF, but doesn't in Safari.

Funny thing: `<tspan>` example from MDN doesn't work in FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `innerHTML` in an SVG document. Create the `tspan` and use `textContent` to set the text...

```
    var year_elements_text_tspan = document.createElementNS(NS, "tspan");
    year_elements_text_tspan.textContent = String(starting_year + i);
    year_elements_text.appendChild(year_elements_text_tspan);
    g_tl.appendChild(year_elements_text);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e834s5L6/

Answer (score 1):

Just use createElementNS() and createTextNode() to create the tspan.

```
    var  tspan = document.createElementNS(NS, "tspan");
    tspan.appendChild( document.createTextNode(String(starting_year + i)) );
    year_elements_text.appendChild(tspan);
    g_tl.appendChild(year_elements_text);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/L01xh1rr/2/)